# Devel::CheckLib syntax errors when trying to install Tree::Suffix

Tags: perl, installation, cpan, suffix-tree

I'm trying to install the [Tree::Suffix](http://search.cpan.org/~gray/Tree-Suffix-0.21/lib/Tree/Suffix.pm) module from CPAN on a Debian testing system, with Perl 5.18.1 installed.

During compliation, I get a bunch of syntax errors and warnings, related to [Devel::CheckLib](http://search.cpan.org/~mattn/Devel-CheckLib-1.01/lib/Devel/CheckLib.pm).

```
  CPAN.pm: Building G/GR/GRAY/Tree-Suffix-0.21.tar.gz

syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 164, near "$mm_attr_key qw(LIBS INC)"
syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 171, near "}"
Global symbol "%args" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 175.
syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 179, near "}"
syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 185, near "}"
Global symbol "@headers" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 192.
Global symbol "@libs" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 223.
Global symbol "@libpaths" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 230.
Global symbol "@libpaths" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 236.
Global symbol "@libpaths" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 240.
syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 252, near "}"
inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm has too many errors.
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 7.
```

Full log is [here](http://pastebin.com/pZdL6FBH).

Am I doing anything wrong? Can somebody please confirm these errors occur when trying to install Tree::Suffix?

If this is a bug, does it belong to Tree::Suffix, to Devel::CheckLib, Perl or Debian?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old bundled version of Devel::CheckLib which is using syntax now invalid in perl 5.18.x. For the details see the freshly created [RT Ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=91418). Probably it will work if you add the missing parenthesis around the `for ... qw(...)` calls.

Comment: Yes, it does work after surrounding `qw(...)` with parentheses. Thanks for taking the time to report the bug!

Comment: I'm getting the same error while installing X11::Xlib. I have 1.02 version of Devel::CheckLib. What am I missing?

Comment: It does not help if you have a newer version of Devel::CheckLib installed, as the inc version has precedence. That said, it helps if you just delete the inc directory.