# X11::Xlib module installation issues syntax error at Devel/CheckLib.pm

Tags: perl, ubuntu, x11

I'm trying to install `WWW::WebKit` by

`cpanm WWW::WebKit`

but when it tries to install the `X11::Xlib` dependency it fails.

See the error log below.

```
syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 164, near "$mm_attr_key qw(LIBS INC)"
    syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 171, near "}"
    Global symbol "%args" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 175.
    syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 179, near "}"
    syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 185, near "}"
    Global symbol "@headers" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 192.
    Global symbol "@libs" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 223.
    Global symbol "@libpaths" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 230.
    Global symbol "@libpaths" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 236.
    Global symbol "@libpaths" requires explicit package name at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 240.
    syntax error at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 252, near "}"
    inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm has too many errors.
    Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 8.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 8.
    -> N/A
    -> FAIL Configure failed for X11-Xlib-0.02. See /home/chankey/.cpanm/work/1412186280.51492/build.log for details.
    -> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'X11::Xlib' is not installed
    -> FAIL Bailing out the installation for WWW-WebKit-0.06.
```

I searched on Google and found this

[Devel::CheckLib syntax errors when trying to install Tree::Suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587171/develchecklib-syntax-errors-when-trying-to-install-treesuffix)

RT ticket says

> The bundled Devel::CheckLib uses the deprecated "for qw()" syntax,
>   which does not work anymore with perl 5.18.x. Please upgrade to a
>   newer Devel::CheckLib, at least version 0.9.

but I'm already using the 1.02 version of Devel::CheckLib. I don't get where is the issue then?

I've installed all the below packages

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev 
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install libxrandr-dev 
sudo apt-get install libxi-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `X11::Xlib` bundles an out-of-date copy of `Devel::CheckLib` with it - if you check the distribution directory, it's in `inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm`. There are a few choices:

- correct the error in the code of that copy of `Devel::CheckLib`;
- remove the whole `inc` directory so that perl uses the installed version of Devel::CheckLib
- comment out the line `use lib qw(inc);` in `Makefile.PL` to stop perl from looking for modules in there (there are no other modules in `inc`).

All have the same effect, and you should be able to continue your installation of `X11::Xlib` undisturbed!

Comment: Thanks. Edited the Makefile to exclude `use lib qw(inc)`.